# A true proven origin of "copy that"

Tags: etymology, slang

I always thought that "I copy that" was derived from an Italian "capisci" (capire = understand), but today I've read that this may be a radio slang only, not being derived from any other phrase.

What is the truth?

Answer (score -2):

Radio slang is correct.

> This term was introduced by truckers operating on Citizen Band radios. Truckers often came up with their own terms and verbage to use on the radio, most often so that law enforcement couldn't understand their messages.
>
> As a little side note, you will often hear the term "Wilco" in conjunction with "Roger"... "Roger Wilco".... For what its worth, "Wilco" is short for "Will Comply". When you say Roger Wilco, you are saying, I receved your message and I will comply.

Source: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091120041302AAYLAeu

Comment: Hi, trillian, and welcome to English Language & Usage. I suspect that your answer was downvoted either because it didn't make clear what part of your answer was a quotation from elsewhere and what part was your own writing (I've fixed that problem), or because it relies entirely on a Yahoo Answers explanation. Your answer would certainly be stronger if you were to find and cite additional sources to corroborate the one that you quote. Please consider taking this step.

Comment: "Roger willco" is redundant and not used in international aviation. "Roger" means received (from the old radio alphabet in which "Roger"meant "R.") " "Wilco" means "I have understood your order and will execute it," which requires that you to have received it.